# Laravel - carregando dados em um array ao realizar querys em laço

Tags: laravel, laravel-eloquent

Estou realizando querys em laço em um controlador e preciso ir carregando as informações em um *array* para depois enviar para uma *view* e imprimir.

Acontece que não sei como inserir os dados da seguinte forma

```
[id_motorista]-> $motoristas[$c]['id'],
[nome]->$motoristas[$c]['nome'],
[valor total de corridas]-> $relatorio
)
```

E ainda estou tendo que usar o ponteiro no array pois o select me enviou um array multidimencional o seguinte select

```
$motoristas = Motorista::all()->sortBy('nome');

// então eu conto o total de motoristas para ser o laço
 $num_mot = Motorista::all()->count();
// aqui declaro o array vazio para ser carregado no laço
$mot_total = array();

//Segue o script, as datas vem de um formulário anterior e estão funcionando corretamente
```

---

```
for($c = 0; $c < $num_mot; $c++){
            $relatorio = Corrida::all()
            ->whereBeTween('momentosolicitacao',["$datas_ini","$datas_fin"])
            ->where('status','Finalizada')
            ->where('motoristas_id',$motoristas[$c]['id'])
            ->sum('valorcorrida'); 
            $id_motorista = (id,motoristas);
            $id_mot = $motoristas[$c]['id'];
            $dadomotorista = $motoristas[$c]['nome'];
            $mot = array($dadomotorista => $relatorio);
            array_push($mot_total ,$id_mot, $mot);
```

Answer (score 0):

A solução foi a seguinte:

Após cada *query* carreguei a Array desta forma

```
 $mot_cham = array(
     'motorista_id' => $motoristas[$c]['id'],
     'motorista_nome' => $motoristas[$c]['nome'],
     'V_total_chamados' => $relatorio,
     'T_chamados' => $chamados,
 );
 array_push($mot_total, $mot_cham);
```

O que me retornou um array multidimensional para ser tratado na *view*